# Apache installation on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: apache-2.2

Install apache by apt-get or need to compile it from source will it make any difference in Security ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no difference when it comes to security unless you have a patch to apply (made by you or taken from someone else).

For better security, you can do other things like:

1. Prevent directory listings.
2. Running apache as non-root user.
3. Assign the correct permissions for your folders/files.
4. And others...

Of course, your requirements can greatly change what you can/should do.

**EDIT:**

There is one more point to add: In the case of installing a package from source, you can apply a patch to fix any bug as soon as it is discovered by the developers. However, you can't do it when installing a debian package (using apt-get) until the ubuntu guys release an update for it and this usually takes longer time.

Comment: I find it easier to maintain and apply security fix if installed by apt-get as you can rely on the distribution security team.